# Maven error executing pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

> Failed to execute goal on project HMOPV-tools: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project HMOPV:HMOPV-tools:jar:1.0.0: Failed to
>   collect dependencies for [commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1 (compile),
>   commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3 (compile),
>   commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6 (compile),
>   commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2 (compile),
>   javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3 (compile),
>   javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1 (compile),
>   net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:3.7.1 (compile),
>   javax.faces:jsf-api:jar:1.2_07 (compile),
>   javax.faces:jsf-impl:jar:1.2_07 (compile),
>   org.richfaces.framework:richfaces-api:jar:3.3.4.Final (compile),
>   org.richfaces.framework:richfaces-impl:jar:3.3.4.Final (compile),
>   org.richfaces.ui:richfaces-ui:jar:3.3.4.Final (compile),
>   dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6 (compile), jdom:jdom:jar:1.1 (compile),
>   log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15 (compile),
>   commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.2 (compile)]: Failed to
>   read artifact descriptor for commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1: Could
>   not transfer artifact commons-lang:commons-lang:pom:2.1 from/to
>   central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connection timed out to
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.1/commons-lang-2.1.pom
>   -> [Help 1]

below is my pom.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>HMOPV</groupId>
    <artifactId>HMOPV-tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>HMOPV-tools</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2_07</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2_07</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4.Final</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-impl</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4.Final</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4.Final</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.5</source>
                        <target>1.5</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>classes</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

can you please help whats the wrong?

Comment: Can you able to access http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Comment: `connection timed out` suggests, that you did not have internet connection at the time of building (or for some other reason couldn't connect to central repo)

Answer (score 0):

Try using manual installation,

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```